# Wifi (RTL8821AE) stops working after some time of using internet on Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: wireless

The Wifi stops working after I've been using the Internet for a while, until I turn it off and turn on again.

The laptop is Lenovo Ideapad 110-15isk.

description: Wireless interface.
product: RTL8821AE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter.
vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.

Comment: What's your `dmesg` output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by installing rtlwifi drivers:

```
git clone http://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git
cd rtlwifi_new
make
sudo make install
```

Comment: In addition to following [Adon Naaman's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/960715/527764), I also turned "secure boot" OFF in the BIOS, in order to get the service working after restarting the system.